# HBase 0.94.17 error Cloning Snapshot

Tags: hbase

I am trying to clone table from snapshot - 'cust_snap' in hbase 0.94.17. i am getting below error. Any clue what is the problem?

> clone_snapsot 'cust_snap' , 'cust_clone'

NoMethodError: undefined method `clone_snapsot' for #Object:0x63bbad6f>

Answer (score 0):

you have typo in the command. 'clone_snapsot' instead of 'clone_snapshot'